# Modify SQL view/add column without join

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

Trying to modify an existing view. It currently returns 32 rows on my DB. Here's the code:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_fnd_la_Statement]
AS

SELECT     
    SH.lease_id, S.expense_id, SH.statement_header_id, S.statement_id AS row_id,
    EC.name AS expense_category, SH.period, S.invoice_number, 
    S.received_date, S.due_date, S.landlord_expense_total, S.prorata_share,   
    S.tenant_expense_total, S.tenant_admin_fee, S.paid_estimates, S.net_due, 
    CASE 
        WHEN s.status = 'O' THEN 'Open' 
        WHEN s.status = 'P' THEN 'In Progress' 
        WHEN s.status = 'D' THEN 'In Dispute' 
        WHEN s.status = 'C' THEN 'Closed' 
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS status, S.approval, 
    dbo.UDF_getExpenseVendor(S.expense_id) AS vendor, S.approved_amount, 
    S.approved_payment_amount, S.disputed_amount, S.held_amount, S.statement_id, 
    EC.expense_category_id, SH.start_date, SH.end_date, S.status AS status_id
FROM      
    la_tbl_statement_header AS SH 
INNER JOIN
    la_tbl_statement AS S ON SH.statement_header_id = S.statement_header_id 
INNER JOIN
    la_tlu_expense_category AS EC ON S.expense_category_id = EC.expense_category_id
WHERE     
    (SH.IsDeleted = 0) AND (S.IsDeleted = 0) AND (EC.IsDeleted = 0)
```

I've got a fourth table called `la_tbl_expense_cap_setup` that has an effective date column and an expense ID that matches expense ID in the `la_tbl_statement` table. What I want is ALL the results from the existing view, plus a new column with the effective date. Some expenses don't have caps, so that row should be NULL in the effective date column. I've tried joining  on the expense IDs but I get a subset of 19 rows.

Answer (score 0):

using a left outer join will give you all the results for table even if it in not in the 4 th table

Answer (score 0):

Try this with a left outer join on the fourth table.

```
    ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_fnd_la_Statement]
    AS

    SELECT     SH.lease_id, S.expense_id, SH.statement_header_id, S.statement_id AS row_id,          EC.name AS expense_category, SH.period, S.invoice_number, 
          S.received_date, S.due_date, S.landlord_expense_total, S.prorata_share,   S.tenant_expense_total, S.tenant_admin_fee, S.paid_estimates, S.net_due, 
          CASE WHEN s.status = 'O' THEN 'Open' WHEN s.status = 'P' THEN 'In Progress' WHEN s.status = 'D' THEN 'In Dispute' WHEN s.status = 'C' THEN 'Closed' ELSE
           NULL END AS status, S.approval, dbo.UDF_getExpenseVendor(S.expense_id) AS vendor, S.approved_amount, S.approved_payment_amount, 
          S.disputed_amount, S.held_amount, S.statement_id, EC.expense_category_id, SH.start_date, SH.end_date, S.status AS status_id, esc.effective_date
    FROM      
            la_tbl_statement_header AS SH INNER JOIN
          la_tbl_statement AS S ON SH.statement_header_id = S.statement_header_id INNER   JOIN
          la_tlu_expense_category AS EC ON S.expense_category_id = EC.expense_category_id
          left outer join la_tbl_expense_cap_setup as ecson esc.expense_id   = s.expense_id
    WHERE     (SH.IsDeleted = 0) AND (S.IsDeleted = 0) AND (EC.IsDeleted = 0)
```

Comment: I think you've got a typo. Do you mean this? 'la_tbl_expense_cap_setup AS ECS ON ECS.expense_id = S.expense_id'. That returns 47 results. I need only the results of the original view, with the additional column containing either an effective date or NULL.

Comment: Yes - that was a type error.  I fixed it in the example. if you only need the original 32 records, perhaps an inner join will do but the expensed in ESC cannot be null or it will limit your record set to less than 32.  Give that a try.  This is just a guess since I don't know the fields and relationships of ESC and the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

OK LEFT OUTER JOIN was mostly correct. I just had to add 'AND (ECS.IsDeleted = 0)' to the new join to make it work properly. I originally had this AND in the WHERE clause, which only returned rows that had an effective date. Here's the correct code. Thanks for the help.

```
SELECT     SH.lease_id, S.expense_id, SH.statement_header_id, S.statement_id AS row_id, EC.name AS expense_category, SH.period, S.invoice_number, 
      S.received_date, S.due_date, S.landlord_expense_total, S.prorata_share, S.tenant_expense_total, S.tenant_admin_fee, S.paid_estimates, S.net_due, 
      CASE WHEN s.status = 'O' THEN 'Open' WHEN s.status = 'P' THEN 'In Progress' WHEN s.status = 'D' THEN 'In Dispute' WHEN s.status = 'C' THEN 'Closed' ELSE
       NULL END AS status, S.approval, dbo.UDF_getExpenseVendor(S.expense_id) AS vendor, S.approved_amount, S.approved_payment_amount, 
      S.disputed_amount, S.held_amount, S.statement_id, EC.expense_category_id, SH.start_date, SH.end_date, S.status AS status_id,
      ECS.effective_date AS cap_eff_date
FROM      
        la_tbl_statement_header AS SH INNER JOIN
      la_tbl_statement AS S ON SH.statement_header_id = S.statement_header_id INNER JOIN
      la_tlu_expense_category AS EC ON S.expense_category_id = EC.expense_category_id left outer join
      la_tbl_expense_cap_setup AS ECS ON s.expense_id = ECS.expense_id AND (ECS.IsDeleted = 0)
WHERE     (SH.IsDeleted = 0) AND (S.IsDeleted = 0) AND (EC.IsDeleted = 0)
```